# Detect on Navigating out of Settings

Tags: android

Im devleoping an app with Accessibility requirements.
in my onCreate() method of MainActivity, im calling service that every 10 seconds is checking if accessibility is ON and if NOT it sends to Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS to ask for enabling.

The problem is I need to find a way (with accessibility settings off) to know if the user has navigated out of the settings page (e.g. press home or back button etc), as this is annoying when you are just about to click on the ON button it sends you back to the general accessibility page.

I tought it can be done onPause() if the user navigates out, but i dont know how to override the intent for Settings.

Here is the whole class that is repeating every 10 seconds:

```
public class AccessibilityWatcher extends Service {
    private static final Intent sSettingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_ACCESSIBILITY_SETTINGS);
    private AlarmManager alarmMgr;
    private AlarmReciever alarmReciever;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private int AccessibilityCheckPeriod = 10000; //in miliseconds

    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("tag", "Accessibility Watcher Created.");
        sSettingsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        sSettingsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        sSettingsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);

        goToSettings(sSettingsIntent);

        //Setup alarm...
        alarmReciever = new AlarmReciever();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("fire");
        registerReceiver(alarmReciever, filter);
        Intent dialogIntent = new Intent("fire");
        alarmMgr = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, dialogIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
        Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
        Date date = new Date();
        time.setTime(date);
        cal_now.setTime(date);
        alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
        Log.d("Alarm","Alarm set to " + time.getTimeInMillis());
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    public void goToSettings(Intent sSettingsIntent) {
        Log.d("tag", "Send them to settings and display Toast!");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enable access for '" + MainActivity.appName + "'", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        startActivity(sSettingsIntent);
    }

    //Alarm recevier get and set new Time
    class AlarmReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.d("CheckIntent", sSettingsIntent.toString());

            if(!AccessibilityS.isEnabled) {
                //Not Enabled  - Set alarm and send to Settings
                Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
                Calendar cal_now = Calendar.getInstance();
                Date date = new Date();
                time.setTime(date);
                cal_now.setTime(date);
                time.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, AccessibilityCheckPeriod);  //Delay 10 seconds
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    alarmMgr.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                } else {
                    alarmMgr.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
                }
                Log.d("Alarm", "New alarm set: " + time.getTimeInMillis());
                Log.i("Accessibility", "Checking permissions.... Result isEnabled is:" + AccessibilityS.isEnabled);
                sSettingsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                sSettingsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                sSettingsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                goToSettings(sSettingsIntent);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It will be helpful if you could post some existing code.